# How to configure wso2is to generate signed and encrypted Openid Connect token?

Tags: openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to configure wso2is to generate signed and encrypted Openid Connect token? And how can I validate these token on client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default OpenID Connect Token is signed by WSO2 Identity Server. To verify the signature you can use a code snippet from this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Verifying+OpenID+Connect+ID+Token+Signatures).

As of the current implementation, we do not support encrypting the id_token out of the box. You do have the liberty to extend the default id_token building logic by writing an extension to encrypt the id_token. (If you want more details I'll update the answer with more details)

---

Update:
ID Token Encryption is supported OOTB with WSO2 Identity Server 5.5.0 onwards. Check https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Testing+OIDC+Encrypted+ID+Token+with+IS

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I checked the link and it was very useful. Just help with encryption logic as it is mandatory  requirement.

Comment: Hi @farasath, I need this solution. could you pls share a sample code ? i am using WSO2IS-5.3.0